# how to use urlencode( ) in my example?

Tags: php, forms, get, urlencode

I checked `php.net` and read a few examples of how `urlencode( )` works but somehow I just can't get it right.  Can someone give me a hand?

it'll be a lot to example so hopefully my brief example would make sense.

I have a page called `2.php` and it was called to show some contents of a `.txt` file choosen in `1.php`.

I am told to make a link for `3.php` and the link should look something like `/3?filename=a.txt`
with filename as `GET` parameter name and Ensure `GET` parameter value is `urlencoded` using the `urlencode( )` function.

but I'm confused how and where I should put `urlencode()` to make it work.

I'll paste my 2.php code here...I simplified the codes a bit...

```
<?php

$fileContents = file("./aaa/" . $_GET["course"] . ".txt");

echo "<table border=\"1\">";

foreach($fileContents as $row)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    $contents = preg_split("/,/", $row);

    foreach($contents as $eachline)
    {
        echo "<td>";
        if(!(preg_match("/@/", $eachline)))
        {
        echo trim(ucfirst($eachline));
        }
        else
        {
        echo trim(strtolower($eachline));
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

    echo "</table>";

    echo "<a href='./1.php'>Choose another txt file</a><br/>";
    echo "or<br/>";
    echo "<a href='.3.php?'>Work with this txt file</a>";
?>
```

BUT…the 3.php option must have a query string appended to it: the name of the text file that was selected in 1, so instead of ./3.php, the url should be something such as ./3?filename=asdf.txt

Use “filename” as the GET parameter name. Ensure the GET parameter value is urlencoded using the urlencode( ) function.

but I'm just not sure how to get it to work....

Comment: Note that this system could be vulnerable to Remote File Inclusion, if not handled properly

Comment: pasted....but kind of simplified it a bit so there's not too much to read but hopefully still able to understand

Comment: be aware that reading filenames with php can be a security issue. think about the following example:

`/3?filename=.htpasswd`

or

`/3?filename=../../etc/passwd`

or

`/3?filename=../any.php`

In all cases, you can read arbitrary information a user should not be able to see. I hope I made that example clear enough

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the part that should be url encoded in the function within the string:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com?q=' . urlencode($search);

OR in html

http://www.google.com?q=<?php echo urlencode($search); ?>
```

Where `.` is the concatenation of 2 outputs.

Comment: but how about the $search? what should that be though? like what's the output? and oh we are allowed to put echo in the link? (Sorry I'm totally new to php.  Still learning)

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it. but if I do it this way...$url = "./3.php?filename=" . urlencode($_GET["aaa"] . ".txt"); I figured if I use $_GET["filename"] will give me the same result as $_GET["aaa"]. Is this also one of the good result for using urlencode? Because if I just use $_GET["aaa"] in 3.php the value can't be found since it's not linked but with the help of "./3.php?filename=" . urlencode($_GET["aaa"] . ".txt"); I can carry on the parameter of $_GET["aaa"] into 3.php